# Remove <p> tags from Twig's markdown_to_html()

Tags: php, html, twig, markdown

I'm using Twig's *[markdown_to_html](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/markdown_to_html.html)* filter, and it works very well.

However, in some use cases, I'd want it to generate HTML, but without the paragraph tags.

For instance, from this Markdown content:

```
Hello, this is **some Markdown**
```

I want the exported HTML to be:

```html
Hello, this is <strong>some Markdown</strong>
```

But the result is currently:

```html
<p>Hello, this is <strong>some Markdown</strong></p>
```

I looked into the filter's source and didn't se any option to do so.

Is there a way to do this, or should I create my own Twig filter?

I'd prefer to avoid the striptags filter if possible, because I don't want to list all the tags I'll allow (unless there is a reverse striptags where you can specify the tags you want removed ?)

Comment: Relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/issues/230)

Comment: What version of `twig` are you using? As you've specified you are willing to write a custom filter for this. Do note you could access the extension you've mentioned in your own extension and alter the output from there

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with PHP? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen you're right, I've omitted it since it seemed implicit, but it's better to make it explicit.

Comment: An answer (now deleted) is the subject is [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422987/how-to-deal-with-a-correct-but-deleted-answer-because-of-chatgpt).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't understand your comment. There was no deleted answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `league/commonmark` which has an ["Inlines Only" extension](https://commonmark.thephpleague.com/2.3/extensions/inlines-only/) for this exact purpose! It will avoid outputting block-level elements like paragraphs, headers, etc. - only things like emphasis and links would be rendered as HTML.

To use it, construct your Markdown converter like this:

```php
<?php

use League\CommonMark\Environment\Environment;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\InlinesOnly\InlinesOnlyExtension;
use League\CommonMark\MarkdownConverter;

// Define your configuration, if needed
$config = [];

// Create a new, empty environment
$environment = new Environment($config);

// Add this extension
$environment->addExtension(new InlinesOnlyExtension());

// Instantiate the converter engine and start converting some Markdown!
$converter = new MarkdownConverter($environment);
echo $converter->convert('Hello, this is **some Markdown**');
```

This will be [more reliable than parsing HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

(I'm the maintainer of `league/commonmark` and would be happy to answer any follow-up questions you might have in the comments)

Comment: Oh nice ! Thank you, I'll make sure to try tomorrow !

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. I've updated my first answer with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my filter, following [Colin O'Dells answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75428717/4834168). This way, it is more robust, and it will allow the usage or creation of more CommonMark extensions in the future.

```php
# src\Twig\CustomTwigExtension.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Twig;

use League\CommonMark\Environment\Environment;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\CommonMark\CommonMarkCoreExtension;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\ConfigurableExtensionInterface;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\InlinesOnly\InlinesOnlyExtension;
use League\CommonMark\MarkdownConverter;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Markup;
use Twig\TwigFilter;
use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

class CustomTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private const CONFIG = [
        'default' => [CommonMarkCoreExtension::class],
        'inline' => [InlinesOnlyExtension::class],
    ];

    /**
     * @return TwigFilter[]
     */
    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('custom_markdown', [$this, 'customMarkdown']),
        ];
    }

    public function customMarkdown(string $str, string $configName = 'default'): Markup
    {
        $env = new Environment();
        foreach ($this->getExtensions($configName) as $extension) {
            $env->addExtension($extension);
        }
        $converter = new MarkdownConverter($env);
        $html = $converter->convert($str)->getContent();

        return new Markup($html, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * @return ConfigurableExtensionInterface[]
     */
    private function getExtensions(string $configName): array
    {
        Assert::keyExists(self::CONFIG, $configName);

        $extensions = [];
        foreach (self::CONFIG[$configName] as $extension) {
            $extensions[] = new $extension();
        }

        return $extensions;
    }
}
```

It is called like this in the templates:

```twig
{{ markdown_content|custom_markdown }} {# to use the default markdown configuration #}

{{ markdown_content|custom_markdown('inline') }} {# to remove all paragraph tags from the result #}
```